# The set of points where oscillation is large is compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ and for $\varepsilon>0$ define the set $D_{\varepsilon}=\{x\in [a,b]: \omega(f;x)>\varepsilon\}$ where $\omega(f;x):=\lim \limits_{\delta \to 0+} \omega (f; U_{[a,b]}^{\delta}(x))$ is the oscillation of the function $f$ at point $x$ and $U_{[a,b]}^{\delta}(x):=(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap [a,b]$ and $\omega(f;E):=\sup\limits_{x_1,x_2\in E} |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ for any $E\subset [a,b]$.

My goal is to show that $D_{\varepsilon }$ is the closed set.

Suppose that $x$ is a limit point of $D_{\varepsilon}$ then $x\in [a,b]$ ($x$ cannot be outside of $[a,b]$). Then for any $\delta>0$ there is $x_1\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)\setminus\{x\}$ and $x_1\in D_{\varepsilon}$, i.e. $\omega(f;x_1)>\epsilon$. Then we can find $r>0$ such that $x<x_1-r<x_1+r<x+\varepsilon$ (or $x-\varepsilon<x_1-r<x_1+r<x$) such that $\omega (f; U_{[a,b]}^{r}(x_1))>\varepsilon.$

Then we can find $x_2,x_3\in U_{[a,b]}^{r}(x_1)$ such that $|f(x_2)-f(x_3)|>\varepsilon.$ Hence $\omega (f;(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap [a,b])>|f(x_2)-f(x_3)|>\varepsilon$ for any $\delta>0$.  Hence $\omega(f;x)>\varepsilon $.

Therefore, $D_{\varepsilon}$ contains all its limit points hence it is closed. Being bounded set it is a compact set.

Is this proof correct? I was wondering does it have any small mistakes?
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small mistakes:

1. Instead of $x-\varepsilon$ and $x+\varepsilon$ should be $x-\delta$ and $x+\delta$.
2. The inequality $\omega(f; (x-\delta, x+\delta) \cap [a, b]) > |f(x_2)-f(x_3)|$ should not be strict.

Essential mistake: from your proof it follows that $\omega(f; x) \geqslant \varepsilon$, not $\omega(f; x) > \varepsilon$. And indeed the set $D_{\varepsilon}$ need not be closed unless it is defined as

$$D_{\varepsilon} = \{ x \in [a, b] : \omega(f; x) \geqslant \varepsilon \}.$$

**Edit:** For the function $f : [0, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ we have that $\omega(f; x) = x$ so e.g. $D_1 = (1, 2]$ is not closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! That was really helpful and I see my mistake.

Comment: However, in these lecture notes the author claims that it is a closed set. See the last page. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/Lebesgue.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjBuIyX6OXyAhXLJt8KHQRnCikQFnoECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0HrnXArhew9gkrf_Vg4BqJ

Comment: @ZFR: In those lecture notes the conclusion of the sentence "This
implies that every neighborhood of $x$ contains points $\ldots$" is not correct. Correctness aside, the implication is not an explicit consequence of the author's previous statements, because the author did not begin with something along the lines of "Let $N_x$ be a nbd of $x$" (and then conclude with $x'$ and $x''$ belonging to $N_x),$ and it is not clear to me how the author's previous statements could allow for a recasting into this form. **(continued)**

Comment: Also note that the neighborhood of $x'$ which contains $x''$ might not be a nbd of $x.$ And even if it were (always) a neighborhood of $x,$ we would still need to show that every neighborhood of $x$ can arise as such a neighborhood (i.e. given a neighborhood $N_x$ of $x,$ it is possible to choose $x'$ and $x''$ and a neighborhood $N_{x'}$ of $x',$ all three of which satisfy the authors various statements concerning them, with the property that $N_x = N_{x'}).$

Comment: @ZFR Then the author is wrong (which happens to anyone). Briefly reviewing the link I found another mistake so I would not trust that all the technical details in the notes are correct. But probably just replace $>$ with $\geqslant$ and it will be fine.

Comment: @Adayah, Can you show an example when $D_{\varepsilon}$ as I defined is not the closed set?

Comment: Please take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4242088/lebesgue-criterion-for-riemann-integrability

Comment: @ZFR I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding mistakes in my reasoning and providing an example! Appreciate it! +1