# Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]

That is the excerpt from Zorich's book (page 346). I am trying to derive part d) from  part c). I've already proved part c).

> Here is the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability: $$(f\in
>  \mathcal{R}[a,b])\Leftrightarrow (f \ \text{is bounded on} \ [a,b])
>  \land (f \ \text{is continuous almost everywhere on} \ [a,b]).$$

*My proof:*

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.  Define the set $D:=\{x\in [a,b]: \omega(f;x)>0\}$, where $\omega(f;x)$ is the oscillation of $f$ at $x$. Then $D=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n$ where $D_n=\{x\in [a,b]: \omega(f;x)>\frac{1}{n}\}.$

Let's fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then by part c) for any $\varepsilon>0$ one can find open intervals $I_1,\dots, I_N$ such that $D_n\subset \cup_{k=1}^{N}I_k$ with $\sum \limits_{k=1}^N |I_k|<\epsilon$. Hence $D_n$ has zero measure. Then $D$ also has zero measure and one can see that $D$ is exactly the set of discontinuities of function $f$. It is obvious that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\setminus D$. Hence $f$ is continuous a.e. on $[a,b]$.

$\Leftarrow$ Since $f$ is continuous a.e. on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\setminus E$ where $E$ has zero measure. Suppose the set $D$ as above. Then $D\subset E$ and $D$ has zero measure.

Let's take $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ and consider two sets $D_{>\varepsilon}:=\{x\in [a,b]: \omega(f;x)>\varepsilon\}$ and $D_{\geq \varepsilon}:=\{x\in [a,b]: \omega(f;x)\geq \varepsilon\}.$ Then $D_{>\varepsilon}\subset D_{\geq \varepsilon}\subset D$ and $D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ has zero measure. Then there is a countable collection of open intervals $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $D_{\geq \varepsilon}\subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k$ and $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|I_k|<\delta.$

If we can show that $D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ is closed set then it is a compact set then there are finitely many  WLOG $I_1,\dots, I_p$ such that $D_{\geq \varepsilon}\subset \cup_{k=1}^{p}I_k$ and $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{p}|I_k|<\delta$ and it also covers $D_{> \varepsilon}$ since $D_{>\varepsilon}\subset D_{\geq \varepsilon}$. Then by part c) it follows that $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$.

**Question:** So the only issue which I have is to show that the set $D_{\geq \varepsilon}=\{x\in [a,b]:\omega(f;x)\geq \varepsilon\}$  is closed set.

Equivalently, we have to show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ is an open set. Since $D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ is the subset of $[a,b]$ then one see that $$\mathbb{R}\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon}=(-\infty,a)\cup ([a,b]\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon})\cup (b,+\infty),$$ and the first and third sets are open. So it suffices to show that $[a,b]\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ is an open set.

In other words, for any $p\in [a,b]\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $(p-\delta,p+\delta)\subset [a,b]\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon}.$

Let's take $p\in [a,b]\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ then $\omega (f;p)<\varepsilon$ and $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\omega(f; U_{[a,b]}^{\delta}(p))<\varepsilon$.

I think that I can prove the result if $p\in (a,b)$ but if $p$ is the endpoint of $[a,b]$ say $p=a$ then $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$ is not a subset of $[a,b]\setminus D_{\geq \varepsilon}$ and it confuses me a lot.

I'd be very grateful if someone can give me a very good explanation and the proof!

Comment: You can just observe that if $\omega _f(p) <\epsilon $ then there is a $\delta >0$ such that $\Omega _f((p-\delta, p+\delta) \cap [a, b]) <\epsilon $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, can you give a more detailed answer please? I know that what you wrote is actually correct but don't see what it should give to us

Comment: Necessity part of Lebesgue criteria can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3742907/121671)